# Implementing Firebase Native Ads in Flutter

Tags: java, firebase, flutter, kotlin, admob

I want to monetise my Flutter app using `firebase_admob` with **Native** ads. In the [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_admob#using-native-ads) page of `firebase_admob` they showed steps for Java only but my MainActivity page is in Kotlin. I don't have any knowledge of Kotlin. How can I implement the same from MainActivity.java to MainActivity.kt?


Java code:

```java
package my.app.path;

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebaseadmob.FirebaseAdMobPlugin;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
  @Override
  public void configureFlutterEngine(FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new FirebaseAdMobPlugin());

    FirebaseAdMobPlugin.registerNativeAdFactory(flutterEngine, "adFactoryExample", NativeAdFactoryExample());
  }

  @Override
  public void cleanUpFlutterEngine(FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
    FirebaseAdMobPlugin.unregisterNativeAdFactory(flutterEngine, "adFactoryExample");
  }
}
```

Comment: you can just create Kotlin class in your project and copy-paste java code there. If you are using Android studio, it should auto-convert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There you go mate

**Note**: The java-kotlin converter converts it pretty good but you have to add one more thing to the ***"customOptions"***, the **"?"** sign to prevent panic attack when the native ad loads on the screen which I already added so you can just copy paste.

**MainActivity.kt**

```
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugins.googlemobileads.GoogleMobileAdsPlugin
import io.flutter.plugins.googlemobileads.GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.NativeAdFactory


class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        val factory: NativeAdFactory = NativeAdFactoryExample(layoutInflater)
        GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.registerNativeAdFactory(flutterEngine, "adFactoryExample", factory)
    }

    override fun cleanUpFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.unregisterNativeAdFactory(flutterEngine, "adFactoryExample")
    }
}
```

**NativeAdFactoryExample.kt**

```
import android.graphics.Color
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.widget.TextView
import com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.UnifiedNativeAd
import com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.UnifiedNativeAdView
import io.flutter.plugins.googlemobileads.GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.NativeAdFactory


internal class NativeAdFactoryExample(private val layoutInflater: LayoutInflater) : NativeAdFactory {
    override fun createNativeAd(
        nativeAd: UnifiedNativeAd, customOptions: Map<String, Any>?): UnifiedNativeAdView {
        val adView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_native_ad, null) as UnifiedNativeAdView
        val headlineView = adView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.ad_headline)
        val bodyView = adView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.ad_body)
        headlineView.text = nativeAd.headline
        bodyView.text = nativeAd.body
        adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW)
        adView.setNativeAd(nativeAd)
        adView.bodyView = bodyView
        adView.headlineView = headlineView
        return adView
    }
}
```

Comment: hi really appreciate mate. the earlier error is gone but new error came up here do you know why this happens? Unresolved reference: my_native_ad Unresolved reference: ad_headline Unresolved reference: ad_body

Comment: Download the lib file from pub.dev there is example project with xml layout you can tweak it to fit your needs. I'll help you if you can't figure out since this topic can be hard to understand in the first go.